# Filtering JSON output

Tags: python, json

I want to filter a JSON output but it gives me the following error:

```
File "main.py", line 40, in on_ready
output_dict = [x for x in a2 if x['type'] == 'ORDER_FILL']
File "main.py", line 40, in <listcomp>
output_dict = [x for x in a2 if x['type'] == 'ORDER_FILL']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

This is my code:

```
json_output = {'transactions': [{'id': '111', 'accountID': 'xxxxx', 'userID': xxxxx, 'batchID': '109', 'time': '2022-01-31T00:50:29.592777450Z', 'type': 'STOP_LOSS_ORDER', 'tradeID': '109', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'triggerCondition': 'DEFAULT', 'triggerMode': 'TOP_OF_BOOK', 'price': '15140.9', 'reason': 'ON_FILL'}, {'id': '112', 'accountID': 'xxxxx', 'userID': xxxxx, 'batchID': '112', 'requestID': '24908231217089037', 'time': '2022-01-31T08:29:58.903631976Z', 'type': 'MARKET_ORDER', 'instrument': 'DE30_EUR', 'units': '-0.1', 'timeInForce': 'FOK', 'positionFill': 'DEFAULT', 'reason': 'CLIENT_ORDER'}, {'id': '113', 'accountID': 'xxxxx', 'userID': xxxxx, 'batchID': '112', 'requestID': '24908231217089037', 'time': '2022-01-31T08:29:58.903631976Z', 'type': 'ORDER_FILL', 'orderID': '112', 'instrument': 'DE30_EUR', 'units': '-0.1', 'requestedUnits': '-0.1', 'price': '15499.6', 'pl': '5.9200', 'quotePL': '5.92', 'financing': '0.0000', 'baseFinancing': '0.00000000000000', 'commission': '0.0000', 'accountBalance': '525.0693', 'gainQuoteHomeConversionFactor': '1', 'lossQuoteHomeConversionFactor': '1', 'guaranteedExecutionFee': '0.0000', 'quoteGuaranteedExecutionFee': '0', 'halfSpreadCost': '0.0850', 'fullVWAP': '15499.6', 'reason': 'MARKET_ORDER', 'tradesClosed': [{'tradeID': '109', 'units': '-0.1', 'realizedPL': '5.9200', 'financing': '0.0000', 'baseFinancing': '0.00000000000000', 'price': '15499.6', 'guaranteedExecutionFee': '0.0000', 'quoteGuaranteedExecutionFee': '0', 'halfSpreadCost': '0.0850', 'plHomeConversionCost': '0.00', 'baseFinancingHomeConversionCost': '0.00000000000000', 'guaranteedExecutionFeeHomeConversionCost': '0', 'homeConversionCost': '0.00000000000000'}], 'fullPrice': {'closeoutBid': '15496.4', 'closeoutAsk': '15504.5', 'timestamp': '2022-01-31T08:29:58.871175423Z', 'bids': [{'price': '15499.6', 'liquidity': '100'}, {'price': '15499.1', 'liquidity': '100'}, {'price': '15496.4', 'liquidity': '100'}], 'asks': [{'price': '15501.3', 'liquidity': '100'}, {'price': '15501.9', 'liquidity': '100'}, {'price': '15504.5', 'liquidity': '100'}]}, 'homeConversionFactors': {'gainQuoteHome': {'factor': '1'}, 'lossQuoteHome': {'factor': '1'}, 'gainBaseHome': {'factor': '15422.8980'}, 'lossBaseHome': {'factor': '15577.9020'}}, 'plHomeConversionCost': '0.00', 'baseFinancingHomeConversionCost': '0.00000000000000', 'guaranteedExecutionFeeHomeConversionCost': '0', 'homeConversionCost': '0.00000000000000'}, {'id': '114', 'accountID': 'xxxxx', 'userID': xxxxx, 'batchID': '112', 'requestID': '24908231217089037', 'time': '2022-01-31T08:29:58.903631976Z', 'type': 'ORDER_CANCEL', 'orderID': '110', 'reason': 'LINKED_TRADE_CLOSED', 'closedTradeID': '109', 'tradeCloseTransactionID': '113'}, {'id': '115', 'accountID': 'xxxxx', 'userID': xxxxx, 'batchID': '112', 'requestID': '24908231217089037', 'time': '2022-01-31T08:29:58.903631976Z', 'type': 'ORDER_CANCEL', 'orderID': '111', 'reason': 'LINKED_TRADE_CLOSED', 'closedTradeID': '109', 'tradeCloseTransactionID': '113'}], 'lastTransactionID': '115'}
        
input_dict = json_output
output_dict = [x for x in input_dict if x['type'] == 'ORDER_FILL'] # Filter if type is this
output_json = json.dumps(output_dict)
print(output_json)
```

Comment: There is no need of `json.loads` here because `json_output` is already a python object

Comment: I edited my question. I have this error :   File "main.py", line 40, in on_ready
    output_dict = [x for x in a2 if x['type'] == 'ORDER_FILL']
  File "main.py", line 40, in <listcomp>
    output_dict = [x for x in a2 if x['type'] == 'ORDER_FILL']
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: The exception make sense, Because `for x in input_dict` yields the dictionary keys in each iteration which is a string.

Comment: `[x for x in input_dict['transactions'] if x['type'] == 'ORDER_FILL']`

Comment: @RJAdriaansen It's working, thank you. Can you write the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will expand on RJ Adriaansen's comment.

Your variable `json_output` is a dictionary. When iterating through dictionary, you are getting dictionary keys (in this case `transaction` and `lastTransactionID`).

What you want is to iterate through the list nested within `transaction` key in the root dictionary. You can do that like this:

```py
[x for x in json_output['transactions'] if x['type'] == 'ORDER_FILL']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to cycle trough the transaction list not the dict:

```
import json
...
input_dict = json_output
input_dict["transactions"] = [x for x in input_dict["transactions"] if x['type'] == 'ORDER_FILL'] # Filter if type is this
output_json = json.dumps(input_dict, indent=4)
print(output_json)
```